# How to Invoke External PHP Web Services with WSO2 ESB

Tags: php, service, wso2-esb

Hello WSO2 ESB community,

I have a services in PHP. I have invoked into WSO2ESB through WSDL proxy and no problem with that. But, when I tried to call it from either SOAP client or 'try this services' built in WSO2ESB, that services can't be called and show an error :

**org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out**

Can you help me what's wrong..? As a note, that's PHP services is goes well when call directly from SOAP client, not through WSO2ESB..

this is my PHP services code..

**

```
<?php
//call library
require_once ('../nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
// Create the server instance
$server = new soap_server();
// Initialize WSDL support
$server->configureWSDL('hellowsdl', 'urn:hellowsdl');
// Register the method to expose
$server->register('hello',                // method name
    array('name' => 'xsd:string'),        // input parameters
    array('return' => 'xsd:string'),    // output parameters
    'urn:hellowsdl',                    // namespace
    'urn:hellowsdl#hello',                // soapaction
    'rpc',                                // style
    'encoded',                            // use
    'Says hello to the caller'            // documentation
);
// Define the method as a PHP function
function hello($name) {
        return 'Hellooo, ' . $name;
}
// Use the request to (try to) invoke the service
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

**

and the client look like this one..

```
<?php
require_once ('../nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');

// Create the client instance

$wsdl="http://localhost:8280/services/HelloNuSOAP?wsdl";
$client =new nusoap_client($wsdl,true);
// Check for an error
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    // Display the error
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    // At this point, you know the call that follows will fail
}
// Call the SOAP method
$result = $client->call('hello', array('name' => 'Scott'));
// Check for a fault
if ($client->fault) {
    echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    // Check for errors
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        // Display the error
        echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    } else {
        // Display the result
        echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
        print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
}

?>
```

on the part of client code,

```
$wsdl="http://localhost:8280/services/HelloNuSOAP?wsdl";
```

is WSDL address from WSO2ESB. **The result when we called it is "request time out"**.

If we change that with direct WSDL address from services server where the services code take placed, let's say

```
 $wsdl="http://localhost/ws/hello_serper_nusoap.php"
```

**the result is server will be invoked succesfully and we'll got a result**.

So, we can make a conclusion that WSO2ESB can't call that PHP web services. Is there any way to invoke php web services on WSO2ESB?

Comment: Can we see your code please

Answer (score 1):

Wow.. i have resolved my problem above..!

the only one cause is because **my PHP services is running on IIS server**.

I have tried change my server to Apache (with wamp).. then access it with SOAPUI through WSO2ESB.

Then..

Viola...  WSO2 ESB read that PHP services successfully without any problem. I only should add my PHP client with PHP cURL Extension to access it if PHP client will be used.

I don't know what happen between IIS and WSO2ESB. Hopefully it can useful for others.

Thank You..